# Quiero usar un cupón de descuento y limitarlo una vez, con php y mysql en laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

[image: Esta es la tabla de mi base de datos en mysql]

Me gustaría saber como hacer un código en php para limitar un descuento(cupón), el descuento lo recibe desde la base de datos.

[image: Este es el código que tengo para que me haga el descuento]

Este es el código que tengo para que me haga el descuento

Comment: Añade tu código en formato texto, las imágenes no son bien recibidas

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el tema está más que nada en entender el concepto que hay asociado a este no tanto en la solución aplicada exactamente.
Me explico:

Tenemos en cuenta que el cupón solo se puede usar una vez, se debe establecer un campo "usado" o similar a fin de tener registro de si se usó ya o no (Veo que hay un campo que dice "expired" si ese campo no se está usando en vez de crear uno nuevo podrías reutilizar este).

Posterior a eso, en el formulario de "uso del cupón" debe por debajo (Desde el controlador que recibe los datos del formulario) debe cambiar el estado de false a true.

Entonces por último se debe validar que el cupón fue usado ya (true) para impedir su uso nuevamente.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).